# Springboot 2.7.2 with Hibernate 5.6 Error ORA 32575 during INSERT

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, sql-insert

Using Springboot 2.7.2 and Hibernate 5.6 with Oracle 12.2 to write a web application.  I use the repository model to do an insert and test with mockmvc.  With SQL Debug turned on I get an error ORA 32575 at the point where it executes the insert statement.  In the debug log it has INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, ID) VALUES ('X','Y',DEFAULT). The Oracle error 32575 follows this.  The ID field in question is part of a Hibernate pojo and is a primary key and uses GenerationType.SEQUENCE.  It is an Entity that points to a Table.

The DataSource is "thin" driver using the ojdbc8.jar.  The Datasource is set up using a @Configuration" annotation in the application during Tomcat startup.  If you take all of this by itself I dont get the error above.

However, I have a requirement to connect to each database user through a PROXY USER account because we use Oracle Label Security.  It looks something like GRANT CONNECT TO userX THROUGH proxyuser. Using the database driver it would be something like

```
Properties proxyProps = new Properties()
proxyProps.set(Connection.PROXY_USER_NAME, user)
oraCon.openProxySession(Connection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME)
```

This is being done inside of an application class called ProxyDelegatingDatasourceThin which extends DelegatingDataSource which is a Spring class that I believe gets called when a new connection attempt is made.

Again, queries work fine, updates seem to work,  its only the INSERTS.  The ID column itself is set to NUMBER and is flagged as a Primary Key.  It is not set as any kind of an IDENTITY column.

The error seems to want the ID column to be omitted from the INSERT Statement all together but Hibernate or Spring is generating it with the DEFAULT in the VALUES that is associated to ID.

Im hoping someone can help.  Spent days on this.

1. Set the @ID column to be nullable, insertable, updatable all set to false
2. Tried using merge and persist from the entity manager (EntityManager) instead of using the Spring Repository save() method.
3. The implicit caching property is set to true

The error seems to want the ID column to be omitted from the INSERT Statement all together but Hibernate or Spring is generating it with the DEFAULT in the VALUES that is associated to ID.

Adding more info...

When I remove the code above which opens the proxy session, I don't get the error.  I also printed some info from the database context while using the proxy session and the PROXY USER is to the PROXY ACCOUNT and the SESSION user is to the user that is connecting through the PROXY ACCOUNT.

Whether I use the Oracle Thin Driver or UCP I get the same result.

Comment: It's helpful to give the full error message (or messages) you get, not just an error number (partly because there are too many error numbers to memorise them all, partly because the same number can sometimes have different meanings). Are you sure you're actually inserting into a table and not a view - particularly if you're now connecting as a different (proxy) user? And if it is a table that it doesn't have a generated ID value? Perhaps you're checking the definition of the wrong object, in the wrong schema? And what happens if you use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`?

Answer (score 0):

This error was resolved by using an updated version of the Oracle Driver ojdbc8.jar